# asp.net Tab Control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a tab control with 2 tabs, 1 tab that validates some controls and the other tab on button click will show me a gridview.

The problem is that when I press the button, it validates the other tab. How can I disable the validation on this tab and on the other tab the validation is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can set controls up in a group and only validate that group. FOr 4.0, this is easy (I believe this is actually 3.5 or maybe even 2.0?):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx

In older versionss of .NET, you can do something like this:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/groupvalidator.aspx